# drupal 6 node_load width conditions

Tags: php, drupal-6

Here is the situation:

I have two content types. Content type a has a cck reference field for content type b.

Now i am trying to load all the nodes from content type a that are referenced to content type b.

Here is the code that i have.

```
$nidcur =  $fields['nid']->content;

$node = node_load(array("field_micselect" => $nidcur));

dpm($node);
```

So I would like to load all the nodes that are related to the nid $nidcur.

thank you

wolfmarter

Comment: Might want to ask here for an answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Should anybody else be looking for this, here is the code that works.

```
  $nidcur =  $fields['nid']->content;

   $referenced_nodes = db_query("SELECT `field_FIELD_NAME_nid` AS `nid` FROM {content_field_FIELD_NAME} WHERE field_NAME_nid = " . $nidcur);
  while ($referenced_node = db_fetch_object($referenced_nodes)) {
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => $referenced_node->nid));

   }
```